# Why do vertices move when trying to box select?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, selection-tools, select

I accidentally hit some buttons and got stuck in some kind of different edit mode. I can't box select anymore, when I try to, the selected vertices will move. I can still select by single-clicking.

I don't really want to reload because I haven't saved the upper torso yet. It's not that much work but I rather don't do it again.

Can someone tell me the magic hotkey to get out (ctrl + z did not work)? And what this mode is?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You've pressed <kbd>W</kbd>. This is mapped to the selection tool and will cycle through the different selection methods if the select tool is already highlighted.

Either press <kbd>W</kbd> until you're back to box select, or click and hold the Selection button in the toolbar below.

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: Thanks a ton! Now I can keep blendering :p